# What is the most practical way of finding out which certificate is the problematic one?

Tags: windows, windows-update, certificate, digital-signature, sysinternals

I've been using [wsusoffline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) for quite sometime, but recently, I've had this problem. The program downloads an update but then immediately deletes it producing the following warning in the log:

> Warning: Deleted unsigned file "H:\Windows\WindowsUpdate\wsusoffline-10\client\w100-x64\glb\windows10.0-kb3172729-v2-x64_ccc19baa66b28b18518e015e10674bd992e258b8.cab"

Here is the [file](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/secu/2016/08/windows10.0-kb3172729-v2-x64_ccc19baa66b28b18518e015e10674bd992e258b8.cab) being downloaded.

Internet research reveals [this thread](http://forums.wsusoffline.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=925) which lets us know that this warning is given when [sigcheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) cannot verify signature of the downloaded file.

In the case of the thread started, the problem was some missing certificate on his machine. I'm getting a different message than him though.

When I run sigcheck like this:

```
sigcheck.exe windows10.0-kb3172729-v2-x64_ccc19baa66b28b18518e015e10674bd992e258b8.cab
```

This is the result I'm getting:

> Verified:       A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.

My question is how do I locate and view the problematic certificate, so I could investiage this issue further?

Comment: Download the update from the catalog website manually and verify the certificate used to signed the file yourself

Comment: kb3172729 Was released back in 2016.  What Windows 10 build are you running?

Comment: Are you sure you should even be downloading this update? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3172729/ms16-100-description-of-the-security-update-for-secure-boot-august-9,-2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem certificate is the certificate *in the file*:

```
PS C:\_test> $signature = Get-AuthenticodeSignature .\windows10.0-kb3172729-v2-x64_ccc19baa66b28b18518e015e10674bd992e258b8.cab
PS C:\_test> $signature.SignerCertificate

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
2383BED52ABD42366137BFA95716AB432BAD6B3E  CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US


PS C:\_test> $signature.SignerCertificate.NotAfter

Wednesday, April 19, 2017 6:07:31 AM
```

Now you can examine properties of $signature.SignerCertificate at your leisure or even export the certificate to a file as per usual, for further processing/storage.